# Model availability inside ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter, custom-model-binder

I have created a new ActionFilter for an ASP.NET MVC application that I'm creating. I have an action which accepts an Http Post and the argument of the action method accepts an object, for which I have created and registered a custom model binder.

I noticed that inside the `IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting` the value for `filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model` is always `null` despite the fact that it looks like the model binder is always invoked before the action filter `OnActionExecuting` method. In contrast to this inside the `IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted` method of the same action filter the value for `filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model` is not null.

Do you guys know if this is by design or a bug? If by design are their any links which describe why this is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Controller Action is responsible for creating the Model and passing it to the View how could the Model exist prior to the action being called?  You don't know what Model is going to be created until after it's happened.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking to modify the model created by the binder. I will find another way.

Comment: The controller action does not create it if the method is POST

Answer (score 1):

Sayed, you usually set a model during the execution of an action. Therefore, it is natural that the model is null during the execution of the OnActionExecuting which occurs before the action is called.