# Model is always null in OnActionExecuting filter asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Model is always null in OnActionExecuting method of ActionFilter in Asp.net core

`(filterContext.Controller as Controller).ViewData.Model`

I found a [worked solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155114/mvc-model-is-null-in-onexecuted-action-filter-or-a-more-elegant-way-to-set-t) in aspnet mvc 3 and it worked in my MVC 5 project. When I use Asp.net core, this problem is still there and there is no DefaultModelBinder.
How can I get Model value in action filter?

Comment: if this is a filter for post method, then looks like you need the Request model, not a View model -> So use `ActionArguments` property of context: [How to get current model in action filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895830/how-to-get-current-model-in-action-filter)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `ActionArguments` on the context to access the model.

```
public class TestActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        //action has parameter "[FromBody]string value"
        string model = context.ActionArguments["value"] as string;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I implement ValidateModelStateFilter and return a ViewResult (with the model in this result like `CustomDefaultModelBinder`) when ModelState.IsValid == false. So its a bad idea when get model by argument name. But thanks for your help